# Ranking Best Deck

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I'm creating a ranking system for a set of decks.
Each decks have different win rates and number of games.
The decks are currently ranked by the win rate, but this isn't accurate at all since some decks may only have one game which is a win (therefore 100%).

Does anyone know a better way of ranking the decks which takes the number of games into account?

Thanks